# In Terraform, how do I apply DiffSuppressFunc on a TypeList with each element in the list being an object following a schema?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-remote-state, terraform-state

##### Brief Context

I am working on coding a Terraform Provider (using the Terraform SDK), which has a resource. The schema of the resource has a couple of attributes, of which one is

```
            "sample_attribute": {
                Type:        schema.TypeList,
                Optional:    true,
                Description: "A sample attribute whose details have been redacted.",
                Elem:        sampleAttributeSchemaExpanded()
            },
```

where `sampleAttributeSchemaExpanded()` returns a list of attributes (`*schema.Resource`) of which some are integers, some are boolean, some are strings, etc.

What I would like to achieve here, is to apply a `DiffSuppressFunc` on `sample_attribute`.

##### The Problem I'm Trying To Solve

When this resource is created (i.e. running `terraform apply`) and the resource is read (i.e. upon `terraform plan` after the first `terraform apply` to check for updates), API calls are sent from the respective methods in the resource to **create** the resource, and **read** the resource respectively.

The problem is that the order of elements (in `sample_attribute`) in the create API call's request and response and the order of elements in the read API call are dissimilar. Owing to this, after the first `terraform apply`, even if no changes are made to the Terraform Configuration, upon running `terraform plan`, a drift (non-null list of changes) is shown, suggesting a change to be made to elements belonging to `sample_attribute`. Restructuring the order of elements in `sample_attribute` in the Terraform Configuration eliminates the drift, but this should trivially not be the solution.

To fix this, I would like to use `DiffSuppressFunc` in such a way that differences are suppressed if the difference between the current configuration(new) and the configuration in the state (old) pertaining to `sample_attribute` is only the order of elements. If real changes are made to an element in `sample_attribute`, the differences are to be shown as usual.

---

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a good example on using `DiffSuppressFunc` with `TypeList` with each element as an object (following a schema), which is why I am blocked. Any insights or a sample on this (or even suggestions, if you think other methods would work) would really be appreciated :)

**P.S.** One suggestion I've taken from my circles is to sort the elements of `sample_attribute` obtained in the read response to align them with the order of elements in `sample_attribute` in the Terraform Configuration, but I'd not want to do that (unless it is impossible to do this by any other means such as `DiffSuppressFunc`).

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I have the exact same use-case and cant come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `DiffSuppressFunc` is:

```
func(k, old, new string, d *schema.ResourceData) bool
```

Unfortunately this signature means that it's only able to work with "string-like" attributes, because other attribute types cannot be provided as a single string in `old` and `new`. This is a limitation of the old Terraform plugin SDK that was originally designed for much older versions of Terraform that didn't yet have full support for lists and maps.

For requirements like this it's typically better to use [the modern Plugin Framework](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework) instead of the legacy SDK. The new framework was designed for modern Terraform and so it supports all of the same types and data structures that Terraform itself supports, including lists of objects.

The framework does not have a feature that's directly analogous to `DiffSuppressFunc`, but you can use the more general [plan modification](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework/resources/plan-modification) features to achieve the same effect. The SDK uses the `DiffSupressFunc` result to reset an attribute back to its value from the prior state, which you can implement yourself in a plan modifier by comparing `req.StateValue` with `req.PlanValue` and then setting `req.PlanValue` to exactly `req.StateValue` to "suppress the diff".

Alternatively, you can define a custom type with [a semantic equality rule](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework/handling-data/custom-types#semantic-equality) to tell the framework how to compare two values of your custom type and decide if they are equivalent. If your type indicates that the two values are equivalent then the framework will automatically retain the prior value, in a similar way as `DiffSuppressFunc` is treated in the old SDK.

If you cannot migrate to the modern Plugin Framework then an an alternative with the old SDK is the resource-level [`CustomizeDiff`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/resources/customizing-differences) function, which is similar in scope to the plugin framework's "plan modification" concept. In a `CustomizeDiff` function you can implement a rule which compares the old and new values for an attribute and uses `d.Set` to override the new value back to the old value when appropriate.

Comment: Hi Martin - thank you so much for your inputs :) it did seem to me that `DiffSuppressFunc` was designed to work only with strings - thanks for sharing similar thoughts.

Unfortunately, I cannot consider the option of migrating to the new Plugin Framework at the moment, and hence, would like to explore the `CustomizeDiff` route (which I've already tried, but in vain). Would you be able to help me out with a little more elaborate explanation on how `CustomizeDiff` would help solve this issue and/or any good references on this? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It's hard to describe a hypothetical solution without reference to what you tried already. Perhaps you could start a new Stack Overflow question where you'd share what you already tried with `CustomizeDiff`, and what problems you encountered when you did so, and then I or someone else could try to suggest how to tweak what you wrote to make it work as you want.